# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Rewrite All Requests From Multiple Directory Depths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using the following code to redirect all requests to one domain to another single page (without stuff after the /)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301]
```

The above works if I go to olddomain.com or olddomain.com/something, but doesn't work when going to olddomain.com/something/somethingelse

How can I get the rewrite rule to work for all directory depths?

Answer (score 1):

Should have worked, You can try this code also:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that my 301 redirect was being cached so it was a client side bug that wasn't wrong with my original code. Upvote for your answer, though.